# Changing binary variables to Yes/No

Tags: r, binary, regression

So I have a data frame that I'd like to analyze.  The problem is that instead of Yes/No, there are a bunch of 1s and 0s (1 being Yes, 0 being No) in the data frame.  How do I modify the data frame to make it so instead of the 1s and 0s there are Yes and No so I can use logistic regression? I am sure there is a simple fix for this that I am not thinking of

Thanks!

Comment: The common way to use logistic regression is with a 1/0 outcome. If all you're trying to do is run logistic regression, it's probably fine to retain the 1/0 encoding.

Comment: Logistic regression will work fine if the response is 1/0. I'm not sure what you mean by yes/no - you want to create a factor variable or something?

Answer (score 8):

Use `?factor`.

See this example

```
> set.seed(1)
> dummyVariable <- sample(c(0,1), 10, TRUE)  # bunch of 0 and 1
> newVariable <- factor(dummyVariable, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))
> newVariable  # this is now a dummy variable ready for regression analysis
 [1] No  No  Yes Yes No  Yes Yes Yes Yes No 
Levels: No Yes
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also just use your values as indices of the `c('no','yes')` vector, adding 1 as your values start at 0.

This will be easy to generalize in case of more than two values, which wouldn't work so well with `ifelse`:

```
c('no','yes')[df$col+1]
```

or

```
factor(c('no','yes')[df$col+1],c('no','yes'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get a factor out of this:

```
factor(ifelse(dummyVariable, 'Yes', 'No'))
```

Comment: you should set the levels, else the results may come off unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Try using `gsub`.

```
dummyVariable<-gsub(0,"No",dummyVariable)
dummyVariable<-gsub(1,"Yes",dummyVariable)
dummyVariable
# [1] "No"  "No"  "Yes" "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "No"
```